# Python - Test Local Shopify App

Tags: python, shopify-app

So i'm new to shopify development but I have an app built in python which I am running locally using `manage.py runserver 8000` The app runs and I am presented with a login/install page.

[image]

I have set up a dev store so I enter this url into the box and click login/install. At this point I am presented with an error

[image]

I am using python and have set the shopify settings

```
SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY = '**hidden**'
SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET = '**hidden**'
SHOPIFY_APP_NAME = 'MyApp'
SHOPIFY_APP_API_SCOPE = ['read_products', ]
SHOPIFY_APP_IS_EMBEDDED = True
SHOPIFY_APP_DEV_MODE = True
```

The hidden settings are set to the API credentials I got from the dashboard. So my app is served locally on http://127.0.0.1:8000. Can I test this app on my dev store without deploying it to Heroku? or does it need to be deployed to test?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my app needed to be using ssl. Using ngok I managed to host http://127.0.0.1:8000 over ssl with a live url

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Allowed redirection URL(s) & App Url in Shopify App Setup
https://partners.shopify.com/

[Here is my App Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JgbC.png)